# Selenium - 'ITimeouts.ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan)' is obsolete

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use the C # project settings implicity:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
```

Everything worked. When I installed the new version of selenium-dotnet-3.1.0 my voice this error:

> Warning   CS0618  'ITimeouts.ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan)' is obsolete: 'This
>   method will be removed in a future version. Please set the
>   ImplicitWait property instead.'

**How to set the global ImplicitlyWait time?**

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I had the same problem. You can use the following code:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solutions.

Comment: By the way, for the next time check the error, the last sentence tells you what you need to use. Also, when you navigate to the original source code with F12, you can read it there.

Comment: Drivers in my folder Selenium but these programs do not work in version **selenium-dotnet-3.1.0**:

IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Selenium\");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Selenium\");
IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(@"C:\Selenium\");

As the driver set correctly?

Comment: yep, I guess if you use older NuGet packages, it will require the old syntax.

Comment: Well I use the syntax that I copied because we use the latest version. You cannot upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

I use Selenium.WebDriver v3.2.0 package (from NuGet), but I can't use ImplicitlyWait property:

```
RemoteDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), _capabilities);
driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(RemoteDriver);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(defaultTimeOut);
```

returns: Cannot assign to 'ImplicitlyWait' because it is a 'method group'

But driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(defaultTimeOut) works well although shows warning about new usage.

Answer (score 0):

Could also use the add method and pass in the TimeSpan:

```
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
```